# Get and update Defaults parameters on Youtube using Youtube API in Java?

Tags: youtube-api

I would like to get and update "Upload defaults" parameters from Channel settings (i.e. allow comments for future uploads, users can vote on comments, etc.) of curently logged in user using JAVA Youtube API, but I don't know how.

Could someone please, help me?

Best,
D

Comment: Can you show us what code you have written so far? Here are the docs on how to use the channel API https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update and some samples to get started https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/java/?r=7601620cab2be176eee28841824d27e0fe5a5e42

Comment: According to developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update, I can not set parameters "allow comments for future uploads" and "users can vote on comments".

Answer (score 0):

This is a known feature request and it is filed internally. Feel free to file a feature request on this to be notified when it's fixed.
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Enhancement%20Request)